# Does a picturebox not support keyboard events?

Tags: c#, forms, events, properties, picturebox

I am currently using Visual Studio, and I don't know if this is a glitch or not, but when I go into the form properties, and show the events, there are two events called <kbd>KeyDown</kbd> and <kbd>KeyUp</kbd>. Now when I do the same for a `PictureBox`, it has way less events and no <kbd>KeyDown</kbd> and <kbd>KeyUp</kbd> events. Does the `PictureBox` support less events then other things? Is this a glitch?

Screenshot of `Form1` properties:

[image]

Screenshot of PictureBox1 properties:

[image]

Comment: Actually a PictureBox can get Focus: `Console.WriteLine("pictureBox  Can Focus: " + pictureBox1.CanFocus);` but it won't receive it from tabbing and won't keep it when something else can get it. But you can set it in code.. However Anup is right about routing keyboard event through the form and the `KeyPreview` events..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a glitch. Its the way it is. You don't type in PictureBox.
If you need to do some task through keys, route it through form only

Comment: I am not typing in the picturebox, I want to trigger something lets say "method1()" when I click the "a" key.

Comment: Yes, that's why you route it through the form. You check which key is being  pressed and call necessary methods

Comment: Will it still work if the picturebox is selected though? For example, the mousemove event won't trigger if my cursor is on top of a picturebox or a button.

Comment: May I please know the exact requirement. It will help me analyze the situation correctly and I'll be able to help you better.
BTW picturebox can not have focus. and Mousemove event will always be Fired even if any other control has focus

Answer (score 7):

As others here have stated, the most appropriate method for capturing keyboard event in this situation is to intercept key events at the `Form` level, as the `PictureBox` control is incapable of receiving focus and lacks exposed key events.

To accomplish this, first set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true` within the designer, or alternatively within the form's constructor:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Then, subscribe to the `KeyUp` event:

```
this.KeyUp += MainForm_KeyUp;
```

Finally, use an event handler similar to as follows to intercept and process key events:

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.A:
            // Perform some action...
            break;
        case Keys.B:
            // Perform some action...
            break;
        case Keys.End:
            // Perform some action...
            break;

        // etc...

    }
}
```

If you intend to "consume" the key from within the event handler, you may set the `Handled` property of the `KeyEventArgs` object as follows:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple trick to handle keyboard events with PictureBox.

Add an handler for MouseEnter and MouseLeave events so to set focus to the PictureBox when the cursor is over. Doing so it will catch keyboard events.

```html
...
_myPictureBox.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(myPictureBox_MouseEnter);
_myPictureBox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(myPictureBox_MouseLeave);
_myPictureBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myPictureBox_event_KeyDown);
...

private void myPictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Focus();
}

private void myPictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 FindForm().ActiveControl = null;
}

private void myPictureBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
  MessageBox.Show("Bye");                
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Focus() you would have to use myPictureBox.Focus(), because Focus() will bring the form into the focus, not the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The PictureBox is used to display images and therefore has no need for keyboard input. It does not take the focus and does not interact with the keyboard.

Comment: You can intercept keyboard messages on the window itself.

Comment: Of course it has a need for the keyboard.  It is quite reasonable to want to scroll the image using the keyboard instead of the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

Event handlers for KeyDown, KeyPress and KeyUp can be added to a PictureBox. For example, in Visual Basic, for a PictureBox called MyPicBox, add a handler for MyPicBox.MouseEnter and put the line MyPicBox.Select() in the handler.
The picture box will now respond to keyboard events. For example, suppose the picture box is showing a visual display of a scientific image. Key combos like Shift-Ctrl-H or Shift-Ctrl-V can be intercepted by a PictureBox.KeyDown handler to invoke some cursor position dependent action such as displaying a cut through the underlying array:

```
 Private Sub MyPicBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyPicBox.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.Shift Then
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.V
                MyCut = Cut.VERTICAL
                Exit Select
            Case Keys.H
                MyCut = Cut.HORIZONTAL
                Exit Select
            Case Keys.N
                MyCut = Cut.NONE
                Exit Select                
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

The keyboard events are listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox

Comment: They are all listed but with the remark _This event is not relevant for this class._. They don't work.